# Defining $\sigma$-algebra on a subset

Tags: measure-theory

This is problem 2.6 from "Probability Essentials" by Jacod. Here's the question and my proof:

Let $(\Omega, \mathbf{A})$ be a $\sigma$-algebra and let $B\in \mathbf{A}$. Show that
$\mathbf{B} = \{A\cap B: A \in \mathbf{A}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $B$. Is it still true when $B \notin \mathbf{A}$?

Proof:$\varnothing = \varnothing \cap B$ and $B = \Omega \cap B$ are both are in $\mathbf{B}$.
If $(A\cap B) \in \mathbf{B}$, then 
$$B\backslash (A\cap B) = B\cap (A \cap B)^c =B\cap (A^c \cup B^c) = B \cap A^c \in \mathbf{B}. $$
So $\mathbf{B}$ is closed w/rspt to complements. Finally, let $(A_n \cap B) \subset \mathbf{B}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$\bigcup_n (A_n \cap B) = B\cap\left(\bigcup_n A_n\right) \in \mathbf{B}.$$
So $\mathbf{B}$ is closed w/rspt to countable unions and $\mathbf{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I'm pretty sure that this is correct. The only thing that's tripping me up is that the proof still holds when $B \notin \mathbf{A}$. I was SO CONVINCED that this theorem would not hold if $B\notin \mathbf{A}$, so I'm just wondering if I missed something here for the second question of the problem. Otherwise, why would the book even ask this question??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true.

It should be noted that from time to time it is worth to limit the context, to help the students focus on the things which are more important for the course. If I were the one writing these problems, then I agree that I would have given the general theorem.

Comment: Thank you! My guess is that if you used a non-measurable $B$ to construct the $\sigma$-algebra, then it wouldn't be compatible with  any measure $\mu$ defined on $\mathbf{A}$, so it's worth it to emphasize that $B$ should be measurable.